# Appropriate data structure to read this file

Tags: logic

I have the following info in a text file.

Item   Rate
pencil  2
eraser  1
laser   3
pencil  1
torch   4
eraser  1

Specifically, I want to know if any item in the above list has a different price.
For eg: In the above one, you can see that pencil has 2 rates ie 2 and 1.
The price of the eraser is same in both entries, so no problem. 
Further complexities - The text file is very huge.

Since dicts don't allow us to store duplicate keys, please suggest ways to solve this problem along with appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Hash Table with Separate Chaining Method.Hope it will works

Answer (score 0):

Does the file have to be plain text ? I recommend tackling this problem by using XML format and parsing it with SAX (not DOM !). SAX will not load the entire file in the memory, so it works well with huge file sizes.

As for the data structure, you could always define your own or you could just use something like this `Map<KeyType, List<ValueType>>`. I feel it's counter-intuitive to have different prices mapped for the same product name. You could create a unique ID for every type of product and have a new field: quantity.